# AmCharts4 disable radar chart resize/zoom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I have this AmCharts4 radar chart in my react application is there any way to disable the click-drag zooming?
Thx.

[Image of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxvBP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the zoom from the chart cursor, you have to set the cursor object's [`behavior`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/radarcursor/#behavior_property) to `"none"`:

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.RadarCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "none";
```

You can find a list of valid properties in the linked documentation and in [this tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/#Cursor_behavior).

Comment: Thx solved it perfectly can't believe I missed it in the docs.